# Change class of dataframe based on other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, class, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe in R that I import from excel and a dataframe that I create with a script. These dataframes contain the same columns but since one is imported from excel, the class of the columns are not identical to the columns of the dataframe created with the script.
The dataframes contain 500+ columns so to do it individually would take a lot of time. Is there any way to change the class of all columns of the excel imported dataframe to the class of the columns from the script created dataframe?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some more information, for example why are the classes different to start with and what kind of data is it?

Answer (score 0):

```r
df1 <- data.frame(a=1,b="2")
df2 <- data.frame(a=1L,b=2,d=3)
nms <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
df2[nms] <- Map(function(ref, tgt) { class(tgt) <- class(ref); tgt; }, df1[nms], df2[nms])
str(df2)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a: int 1
#  $ b: chr "2"
#  $ d: num 3
```

Granted, `$a` remains integer instead of being cast to numeric; if that's not a concern, then that may suffice. If not, then this more-verbose and more-flexible option might be preferred:

```r
cls <- sapply(df1[nms], function(z) class(z)[1])
df2[nms] <- Map(function(tgt, cl) {
  if (cl == "numeric") {
    tgt <- as.numeric(tgt)
  } else if (cl == "integer") {
    tgt <- as.integer(tgt)
  } else if (cl == "character") {
    tgt <- as.character(tgt)
  }
  tgt
}, df2[nms], cls)
str(df2)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a: num 1
#  $ b: chr "2"
#  $ d: num 3
```

The rationale behind `sapply(.., class(z)[1])` is that some classes have length greater than 1 (e.g., `tbl_df`, `POSIXct`), which will spoil that process.